# I want to change status when click selected dropdown

Tags: angular, angular8

when I select dropdown I want to status change to 'In Progress' but now function in app.ts isn't working.

app.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="assign">Assign task to dev</label>
      <select name="assign" class="form-control" id="assign">
        <option value="">choose dev...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let staff of Staff" (click)="assignDev(ticket.status, ticket.id)">
          {{staff.firstName}} {{staff.lastName}} 
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

app.ts

```
  assignDev( id: string, status: any){
    this.ticketService.assignDev(id, status)
  }
```

app.service.ts

```
  async assignDev(id: string, status: string) {
    this.afs.collection('ticket').doc(id).update(status === 'In Progress')
  }
```

Comment: You're passing the arguments in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "click" is not a valid option for select instead use "change" event on it :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label class="control-label" for="assign">Assign task to dev</label>
      <select name="assign" class="form-control" id="assign" (change)="assignDev($event.target.value)">
        <option value="">choose dev...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let staff of Staff" [ngValue]="staff">
          {{staff.firstName}} {{staff.lastName}} 
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In your TS file:

```
 public assignDev(value: string){
    console.log(value);
  }
```